# Closed and bounded but not compact in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: compactness, lp-spaces

I am reading the paper "*The Kolmogorov-Riesz Compactness Theorem*", which gives a characterisation for totally bounded subsets of $L^P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $1 \le p <\infty$.

A subset $\mathcal{F} \subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is totally bounded iff

i) $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded.

ii) $\forall \varepsilon>0, \ \exists\ R$ such that, for every $f \in \mathcal{F}$ $$\int_{|x|>R} |f(x)|^p\,dx < \varepsilon^p ,$$

iii) $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists\ \rho >0$ such that for every $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|y|< \rho$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x+y) -f(x)|^p\ dx <\varepsilon^p . $$

I was trying to find a subset of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is closed and bounded but not compact. For this I need a set which does not meet the criteria ii) or iii). Then it will not be totally bounded and hence not compact. Any help in finding this type of set?

Comment: For $n=1$, take $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$. Do something similar for other $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The closed unit ball in a normed space is closed and bounded but compact if and only if the space is finite dimensional. You can find a proof that uses Riesz's lemma [here](http://planetmath.org/compactnessofclosedunitballinnormedspaces).

Comment: But how can I show that this does not satisfy ii) or iii)?